# Trying to get a openVino IR from a frozen TF model

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, intel, openvino

I have a given inceptionV2 model I want to get working on the rPi, using the NCS2. Examples work fine. Now, the model I am given is a built upon the ssd_inceptionv2 demo, which I know works, since I've been able to convert that demo's frozen pb to IR bin and xml files, and successfully run them on the pi. However, when I try to convert the given model to an IR, it fails. To be more specific, it fails in different ways, depending on how I go about trying to convert it.

The given model has a frozen .pb file, checkpoint files and a .pbtxt. Converting the .pb file the command I'm using is:

```
python3 /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo_tf.py 
  --input_model frozengraph.pb 
  --tensorflow_use_custom_operations_config /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_v2_support.json 
  --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline "PATH"/pipeline.config 
  --reverse_input_channels 
  --data_type FP16
```

this gives the input shape error, which I remedy with `--input_shape [1,299,299,3]`, but it only leads to the error:

> Cannot infer shapes or values for node
>
> "Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/SortByField/TopKV2"

So I try both re-freezing the model and running the conversion on the graph.pbtxt. For both methods, it throws errors since the number of nodes is 0 and 1 respectively.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are able to detect the objects using the frozen graph, try once by changing the command line argument to **tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config** also which **pipeline.config** file are you using? You should be able to create IR files if you are using the **pipeline.config** file which was generated along with the frozen graph for your custom model.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow models can be a bit tricky, especially when you modify those in the model zoo, which are already quite complex. There's a few things I'd like to mention for your scenario:

In [this OpenVINO guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Using-TensorFlow), at "*Using TensorFlow*-Specific Conversion Parameters*", you'll find that

> Models produced with TensorFlow* usually have not fully defined shapes (contain -1 in some dimensions). It is necessary to pass explicit shape for the input using command line parameter --input_shape or -b to override just batch dimension. If the shape is fully defined, then there is no need to specify -b or --input_shape options.

<sup>Some examples of that include [this Openvino issue/answer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/computer-vision/topic/802492#comment-1932592), and a couple more in the [Model Optimizer's guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-ModelOptimizer) in the "*Advanced Topics about the Model Optimizer Internals*" section.</sup>

For the record, I was able to convert a fine-tuned **faster_rcnn_inception_v2** from the model zoo without specifying the `--input_shape` argument, so it really depends on your model.

Also, this might be a typo or version problem, but the `--tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline` argument is officially `--tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config` (as mentionned by @Bhargavi).

Finally, a good way to debug your converting commands is to use the `--log_level DEBUG` parameter to see the full output.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link

http://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/R5/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_tf_specific_Convert_Object_Detection_API_Models.html

Your command looks similar to :

```
<INSTALL_DIR>/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo_tf.py --input_model=/tmp/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb --tensorflow_use_custom_operations_config <INSTALL_DIR>/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_v2_support.json --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config /tmp/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config --reverse_input_channels
```

Please carefully read the section within Custom Input Shape in the documentation.Please add a
--log_level DEBUG to see more details of your MO failure.

Hope this helps.